# embed .caf into a static library .a is it possible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, static-libraries

I am able to play a .caf or an .mp3 file when I place it as a resource inside my project. like below.

```
NSString *mp3Path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"beep" ofType:@"caf"];
NSURL *mp3Url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:mp3Path];
_player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:mp3Url error:nil];
_player.numberOfLoops = 8;

[_player play];
```

But for some reasons, I need to generate a static library .a from my project and wish to embed this .caf or .mp3 file inside the .a library.

is it possible at all? if it is, could you tell me how? because I couldn't find any sample doing a similar thing online.

Answer (score 0):

It's not usual to include resources in a static library. Usually they are included in a `.bundle` file. You can generate a `framework` that contains the static .a library, the bundle file and headers.

Comment: you said "It's not usual" you mean it's doable? because although I can go with workarounds, I prefer to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: Yes I can imagine any file can be saved inside the compiled static library and decoded afterwards. I saw this solution but haven't tried it http://atastypixel.com/blog/compiling-image-resources-into-a-static-library/. If it's too cumbersome, including a bundle file that contains the images is the usual solution.